# Regarding converse Proofs in Analytical Geometry

Tags: proof-writing, analytic-geometry

This is a problem which has been bugging me for long. We know that a relation is called an equation to a curve if every point on the curve satisfies the equation and every point which satisfy the equation lies on the curve.

But when we derive the equation of a curve we only prove that every point on the curve satisfy the equation and we omit the converse.

For example, let us say we want to find the equation of a line making a given angle with the positive direction of axis of x and with a given intercept on the axis of y.

[The derivation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcLTz.png)

As you can see the converse is omitted. Also I haven't found any text which satisfactorly proves the converse. I tried proving it myself and it uses classical geometry.
So my question is the converse not really necessary or can you provide a text in which the converse is proven in every case.

Comment: You are correct. One should indeed prove the converse in every case where it is not trivial. But in analytic geometry one is mostly interested in finding an equation and computing measurements with that equation. In modern geometry, however, we always care if the converse can be shown.

Comment: Also, please be careful of using tags to your questions. `fake-proofs` is really not an appropriate tag for this question.

Comment: @sadman-ncc I thought fake-proofs will be a good tag as we are omitting some part of proof.

Comment: Please take a look at the description of the tag properly before using it. It is good practice to avoid using irrelevant tags.\

"Seemingly flawless arguments are often presented to prove obvious fallacies (such as 0=1). This is the appropriate tag to use when asking "Where is the proof wrong?" about proofs of such obvious fallacies."